# linq to sql error

Tags: linq-to-sql

in my db,i have 4 tables employee,customer,product & orders.

i m trying linq to sql and wrote the following expression:

```
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
var matchingEmployees = from employee in db.Employees
                        where employee.emp_city = "pune"
                        select employee;
```

but it reflects following error:

`Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'`

i have given `emp_city as nvarchar(50)` 
how to resolve the problem

Answer (score 4):

```
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext(); 
var matchingEmployees = from employee in db.Employees 
                        where employee.emp_city == "pune" // == not =
                        select employee;
```